# Regex to match ? from URL but not from query string

Tags: regex

Below is my regex to replace ? chars from a URL.

```
[?](?![-\w%+]+=|$)
```

Its working, but with some caveats. If the query parameter name contains characters which are not specified in the regx character set, it breaks.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: `(?![^?]+=|$)` would help, I suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use negated class

```
[?](?![^?]+=|$)
```

`[^?]` will look for any character that isn't `?`